# Downloading folders of data from AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to download folders from amazon web services (aws) EC2. How can I do that using wget command? I am on Ubuntu and have installed aws-cli.

Comment: Can I have some clarification? Are you talking about folders in S3? Or folders on an EC2 instance? If you mean S3, then you can use awscli without using wget. If you mean an EC2 instance, then you still don't need wget because you can use scp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wget` only if the folder id web-accessible, you must know the path to the folder then (`http://domain.com/path/to-folder`)

If it is not web accessible you can use `scp` or `rsync` to get the content, e.g:

`rsync -e 'ssh -i /path/to/key.pem' -av user@host.tv:~/from/ /local/path/to/`

Make sure 'from' is really correct path.

Also, you may want to set up sFTP and use it as well.

Comment: I tried using scp but it says: No such file or directory found. I have used ssh to check the directory of the ec2 instance and it shows them as present. I dont know why scp cant find it and ssh can.

Comment: Also, how do I setup sFTP for it?

Comment: Which certificate do I need to add? I am new to it and dont know much about it.

Comment: @leehuang, I think a brief introduction to a tool like rsync will probably benefit you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps

Comment: Thanks. That's a very helpful link

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it manually;

zip the folder then download.